# discrete graphs of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I want to see the graph of the function `$x^2-x-1$` in the set of odd natural numbers only the what will be the LaTeX code? For the set of reals `$0\leq x\leq 10$`, I used following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xmin=1, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
]
\addplot[domain=1:10,green,]{x*x-x-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You always enhance the probability of getting an answer soon, when you present a minimal working example, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Answer (score 7):

Like this? It's a `ycomb` plot with `samples at` odd natural numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xmin=1, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
]
\addplot+[ycomb, domain=1:10, samples at={1,3,...,9}, blue]{x*x-x-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Comment: Very very good. I vote +1 your answer.