# discrete line spectrum

Tags: line

[image: ****]

I want to produce this image. I have no data. This is a periodic trig function with different amplitudes. specifically I want to have sticks with "no" volume. Thank you for helping.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373679/discrete-graphs-of-a-function/373684#373684 might be good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), which is built-in to the `lualatex` version of LaTeX.

[image]

I've defined a simple macro that takes a variable number of discrete values as arguments, then plots them as sticks with automatically adjusted axes and labels.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef stick_plot(text t) = 
    % count the list of numbers and store them in "values[]"
    % using a "text" parameter allows the macro to have any number of arguments
    numeric n, values[]; n = 0;
    for i=t:
        values[incr n] = i;
    endfor

    % set some unit size parameters -- in postscript points 72=1in, 1cm=28.35
    numeric u, v; u = 20; v = 4;

    % make the axes to fit the data
    path xx, yy;
    xx = origin -- (n * u + 3/2 u, 0);
    yy = origin -- (0, max(t) * v + 2v);

    % make the arrows a bit sharper
    ahangle := 30;

    % make a <picture> variable to return
    image(
        % draw the data lines -- with labels on even k 
        for k=1 upto n:
            draw (k * u, 0) -- (k * u, values[k] * v) withcolor 2/3 blue;
            if not odd k:
                label.bot("$" & decimal k & "$", (k * u, 0));
            fi
        endfor
        % add the axes with labels
        drawarrow xx; label.bot("$k$", point 1/2 of xx shifted 12 down);
        drawarrow yy; label.lft("$A[k]$", point 1/2 of yy);
    )
enddef;

beginfig(1);
draw stick_plot(4,2,12,18,16,8,3,1,0,7,14,10,2,1);
draw stick_plot(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) shifted 80 down;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You need to compile this using `lualatex`.

If you want more sophistication, you could consider adding parameters for the labels, the spacing, and the colours.  For more on Metapost, follow the link at the top.